# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar showing up with floating objects - only in IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, scrollbar

This site that I coded www.malthestigaard.com gives me an unwanted scroll bar in IE11 only (as far as I know). How to get rid of it?

[image]

Maybe the floating elements are causing it somehow?

I also have some media queries in the CSS, but they seem irrelevant here, please let me know if I need to post them. You can of course see the full code on the website.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class=textclear>
                <div class="alignleft">
                    <h1 class="firsth1"> <a href="http://www.malthestigaard.com"> MALTHE STIGAARD </a></h1></div>
                <div class="alignright">
                    <ul>
                        <h1><li> <a href="#work" type="button"> WORK </a></li><li> <a href="#about" type="button"> ABOUT </a></li><li> <a href="#contact" type="button"> CONTACT </a></li></h1></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%
}

.content-wrapper,
.copytext,
.wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

nav h1 {
    color: #00697f;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-margin-before: .83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: .83em
}

#banner,
.textclear {
    overflow: auto
}

.alignleft,
.circular {
    float: left
}

.alignright {
    float: right
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline
}

h1 {
    font-size: 200%!important;
    width: 100%
}

.firsth1,
nav h1 {
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow: auto` is a bit of a hack for resolving a container with floats. You can get rid of the scrollbar like this. Change:

```
#banner,
.textclear {
    overflow: auto
}
```

to:

```
#banner {
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon Uleis. It worked perfectly :-)